# Can ESX handle multiple File Manager instances?

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine, file-manager, esx

This might be a simple question, but can ESX handle multiple File Manager instances in multiple threads? Or must I queue file tasks to work in series?

Comment: You should clarify your question. Are you referring to tasks running inside Windows VM guests on ESX ?

Comment: I'm referring to tasks running on ESX alone, regardless of VM.

Comment: For example, on a standard 1GB network, up to 4 concurrent vMotions can be performed between two hosts.  See: http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere5/r50/vsphere-50-configuration-maximums.pdf.

Comment: @AdiDembak Thank you. This document helped. Please turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESX hosts can handle multiple file operations, such as migration,vmotion, storage vmotion, etc'

For example, on a standard 1GB network up to [4 concurrent vMotions](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere5/r50/vsphere-50-configuration-maximums.pdf) can be performed between two Vsphere 5 ESX hosts. On a 10GB network, up to 8 concurrent vMotions.

The limits are the result of an overall consideration of modern hardware capabilities.